# Use of permutation/combination in Geometric problems

Tags: permutations, combinations

**There are $p$ points in space, no four of which are in the same plane with exception of $q$, which are all in the same plane. Find out how many planes there are each containing three of the points**?

My question is: what makes you think that you can use permutation or combination to crack this problem?

Comment: We are counting the ways to **choose** $3$ points from $p$, where certain choices are counted as "the same" because they determine the same plane.  So for example if $q=0$ (or $1$ or $2$ or $3$) and $p\ge 3$ the answer is $\binom{p}{3}$, a clearly "combinations" answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think the $p \geq 3$ condition isn't needed?

Comment: It isn't. But $\binom{2}{3}=0$ can add a dose of mystery.